# VLC plays an mp4 but mpv doesn't

Tags: vlc, ffmpeg, mpv-media-player

I have videos that I have ripped off a streaming site, the vast majority play with mpv.

One or two, I get the error:

```
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: Invalid sample size -3
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: error reading header
[lavf] avformat_open_input() failed
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: Invalid sample size -3
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: error reading header
[lavf] avformat_open_input() failed
Failed to recognize file format
```

If I fire up VLC, I get:

```
avcodec decoder: Using Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile - 2.4.0 for hardware decoding
```

And all is good.

Is this an ffmpeg issue?.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Video drivers/ffmpeg is well beyond me.

**ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)**

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu you use ? Latest version of ffmpeg is 4.4-6ubuntu5

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (2 years after the original post) using `ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1` on Xubuntu 22.04. Also, it did not help in any way to build mpv and ffmpeg from source (i.e. from master branch each).